# Double "select row based on value in column"

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I need to select an entire row based on criteria value="REZ" in column "C".

```vb
Dim c As Range
Dim rngG As Range
 
For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("C"))
 
    If c = "REZ" Then
        If rngG Is Nothing Then Set rngG = c.EntireRow
        Set rngG = Union(rngG, c.EntireRow)
    End If
 
Next c
rngG.Select
```

Each selected row has some value in column "J".

I now need to additionally select all entire rows that contains those values gotten from first step.

Images to better explain:
First get rows with "REZ" in column "C"
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwHzT.png]

Now we know that rows value in column "J" which in this case is "27.2.12".
So now in addition to what we have selected we need to select all the rows that contain "27.2.12" which is ALWAYS some number of rows directly after the row found and selected in step 1 and never match exactly as each value in column "J" is unique.

In this case it would be:
[image]

I imagine two IF functions where the second one takes the info from the result of the first.

Workbook example: https://easyupload.io/yewg9o

I highlighted "REZ" rows with yellow that are selected in step 1 and cells that I expect to be selected based on step 1 are highlighted with green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngG As Range, lastJ, rngJ As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each c In Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns("C"))
        Set rngJ = c.EntireRow.Columns("J")
        If c = "REZ" Then
            AddRange rngG, c.EntireRow
            lastJ = rngJ.Value   'remember the J value
        Else
            'not REZ, but see if we're to check for matching J values
            If Len(lastJ) > 0 Then
                If rngJ.Value Like lastJ & "*" Then
                    AddRange rngG, c.EntireRow
                Else
                    lastJ = "" 'stop checking on first non-match
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    rngG.Select
End Sub

'Utility sub for building up a range
Sub AddRange(rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It works like charm! I wonder what does the second sub do exactly? Sorry if it's a silly question

Comment: Not a silly question - all it does is remove a bit of logic from the main code: building up a range by parts is a common operation which can benefit from being in its own method.  When you get to the point where you have a need to do this action in multiple workflows, you already have it sitting there ready for use.